# Is it dangerous to remove "magic_quotes_gpc" from .htaccess file?

Tags: php, sql, ini

I'm installing `phplist` under my server that is based on cgi mode. I read that I have to hide the part related to "magic_quotes_gpc" on .htaccess file and that I also need to configure php.ini file so to allow magic quotes.

I have configured a separate database for phplist different from that of my site.
So is there anything dangerous about that? What is it about "sql injectors" ?

I'm using PHP Version 4.4.9

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118505/what-are-magic-quotes-runtime-in-php

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?
magic_quotes_gpc has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: You should look into switching to PHP 5. PHP 4 is massively outdated and no longer supported

Comment: Agree with pekka, you should absolutly update PHP. If you're conserned about security, updating to PHP 5.3 should be on top of your todo-list

Comment: well the server allows me to choose between php 4 or 5 so this is not a big problem to me, I can choose to use php 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely not "dangerous".

This functionality has been deprecated in PHP 5.3, so it will be the normal move to remove it.

Considering sql injection, even with magic_quotes activated you would have to do some checks, so nothings change here.